# Does the sequence converge or diverge? $a\cdot n+ n[\sin(\pi/n)]$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I used the squeeze theorem as follows:
$-n \le \sin(\pi/n) \le +n$

Then I took the limit for all three and came out with:

$-\infty \le \sin(\pi/n) \le +\infty$

Then I concluded that the sequence diverges because it oscillates between -infinity and +infinity. I don't know if my work was "legal" or not. If it wasn't, could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: I formatted your question.  Please check that it matches your intent.  In particular, the term $an$ in the title does not appear in the question-should it be there?

Comment: The argument that a series is "bounded" by positive and negative infinity means that it is divergent is incorrect. That bound is true for every sequence.

Comment: There is a much better bound for $\sin(\pi/n)$.

Comment: What is $\,an\,$ , anyway? Is it $\,a_n\,$ or a constant times $\,n\,$ ? And if the former, then what sequence is that?

Comment: Also, in the title there is an $n$ multiplying the $\sin (\pi/n)$ that is not in the body.  Your bounds seem to imply it should be there.  Please clarify.

Answer (score 3):

That's not how the squeeze theorem works:

If $\forall x \ f(x) \le g(x) \le h(x)$, and $\lim_{x\to c} f(x) = \lim_{x\to c} h(x) = L$, then $\lim_{x\to c} g(x) = L$.

Your two outer limits do not match, so it cannot be applied at all.

It diverges, but for a different reason. $\sin{x} < x$ for $x \in (0,\infty)$, and $\sin{x} \ge 0$ for $x \in (0, \pi/2]$. Therefore, for all  $n \ge 2$
$$0 \le \sin{\frac{\pi}{n}} < \frac{\pi}{n}$$
$$0 \le n \sin{\frac{\pi}{n}} < \pi$$

If $a > 0$, $an \to \infty$. If $a < 0$, $an \to -\infty$. Adding a term that can be, at most, $\pi$ and at least $0$, will not affect that.

However, if $a = 0$, then this converges to $\pi$, using L'Hôpital.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: taking the limit of **the function**

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}x\sin\frac{\pi}{x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin\frac{\pi}{x}}{\frac{1}{x}}\stackrel{\text{l'Hospital}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{-\frac{\pi}{x^2}\cos\frac{\pi}{x}}{-\frac{1}{x^2}}=\ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this post until this evening, so the essence of my (experimental) method won't be different than the already posted ones. This might be considered a question, as well, due to its disputability.

Just like @DonAntonio stated, we can rewrite the expression:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}{x\sin{\frac{\pi}{x}}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin{\frac{\pi}{x}}}{\frac{1}{x}}$$

I know this really reminds of the derivative definition and leads to L'Hospital, but I tried to avoid that since we haven't formally gone through derivatives at the university.

From the squeeze theorem we already now:
$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}{\frac{\sin x}{x}}=0\;\&\;\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}{\frac{\sin x}{x}}=1$

Why not use the second one in this case?
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\sin{\frac{\pi}{x}}}{\frac{1}{x}}=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\sin{\frac{\pi}{x}}}{\frac{\pi}{x}}\pi=\pi\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\sin{\frac{\pi}{x}}}{\frac{\pi}{x}}$$
$$x\to\infty\implies\frac{\pi}{x}\to0$$
Substitution: $\frac{\pi}{x}=t,\;\&\;t\to 0$
Now we have:$$\pi\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin t}{t}=\pi\cdot1=\pi$$
For the second part involving $an$, I would like to mention an example from our exercises:
$$a_n=\frac{3^n+(-2)^n}{3^{n+1}+(-2)^{n+1}}+(1+a)\sin\frac{n\pi}{2}$$
The conventional method is to find all the accumulation points of the sequence and put a constraint on the final expressions so they are equal because *a convergent sequence has only one accumulation point a.k.a limit*

I was too lazy to analyze all that because if we know (and we do now) that:$\frac{3^n+(-2)^n}{3^{n+1}+(-2)^{n+1}}$ converges, while $\sin\frac{n\pi}{2}$ oscillates, $a=-1$ saves us from suffering.