# Find accumulation points of $a_n=\alpha(3-\frac{1}{n})^{n^{(-1)^{n}}}+\sqrt[n]{2^{n(-1)^n}+6^{n(-1)^{n+1}}}$ regarding $\alpha$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I solved it for $\alpha<0$ and $\alpha>0$. I can't find limit of $\alpha(3-\frac{1}{n})^n$ (the $n$ is even) when $\alpha = 0$. Solution says that this limit is equal to zero but i don't know why it says so because non alpha part goes to infinity and $0*\infty$ is undefined

Comment: [This is a bit related](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3488302/721644).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if $\alpha=0$ then:
$$\alpha\left(3-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=0\left(3-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=0 \quad\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$$
so it's not a $0 \cdot \infty$-type limit.